# How to Map Model to Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Whenever I try to debug my .NET Core 5, I get this error -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'The property
> 'Report.CampaignIds' could not be mapped because it is of type
> 'int[]', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity
> type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the
> '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'.'

No idea how to fix it but I have a clue where the error it's coming from.

This is my model

```cs
public class Report : EntityBase
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public string[] Locals { get; set; }
    public string[] Regions { get; set; }
    public int[] CampaignIds { get; set; }
    public int[] AgentIds { get; set; }
    public IList<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public IList<User> Agents { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the OnModelCreating method I have this

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(x => x.Locals).HasConversion(y => string.Join(',', y), y => y.Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(x => x.Regions).HasConversion(y => string.Join(',', y), y => y.Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

I'm assuming here in the building I need to map the campaignIds to the campaign model.

The question is how can I save the campaignIds and the agentIds in the database right now only the locals and regions are being save.

Class created for the many to many relationship.

```cs
public class ReportCampaign
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
    public Report Report { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. Does `CampaignIds` refer to another entity/table? If so, you should either introduce a relation table (if it's a many-to-many relation) or only have the related entity have the ID to the `Report`.

Comment: Yeah the CampaignIds its another table and its a many to many relationship. Campaigns can have many reports and report can have many campaigns. I created this class following your advise. posted in the original question call ReportCampaign

Comment: Exactly, then you don't need `CampaignIds` (and I guess `AgentIds` as well). Instead you need to make sure EF sees it as a [many-to-many relation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many).

Comment: Ok thanks. i was the front-end developer and the back-end developer (that got trained) left the company and I got throw into the wolfs with no training and expecting to know all this stuff. you save my day.

Comment: As the error says, I think you should change the data type of CampaignIds. It says you can not save this type in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to

```
public class Report : EntityBase
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public string[] Locals { get; set; }
    public string[] Regions { get; set; }
    public IList<Campaign> Campaigns { get; } = new List<Campaign>();
    public IList<User> Agents { get; } = new List<User>();
}
```

And EF will place the Foreign Key (shadow) properties on the Campaign and User entities.